# Why does is think the column is the parameter value

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I get SQLite.SQLiteException: 'no such column: osborne' when I run this code. osborne is my search term, not the column. The column is LastName. Here is the queryasync code

```
public Task<List<DataItem>> GetItemByLastName(string s)
        {
            return Database.QueryAsync<DataItem>("SELECT * FROM [DataItem] WHERE [LastName] = "+s);
        }
```

s contains the search term osborne which I call via

```
var tItem = await App.Database.GetItemByLastName(s);
```

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images!

Comment: further, the code you posted is not helpful - where is your DB model and the code for `GetItemByLastName`?

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to generate queries, that's how SQL injection attacks happen. Google for `Bobby Tables`. Use parameterised queries instead. Which package are you using?SQLite-net perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because you tried to concatenate the query string with a variable to get the final query. What you ended up was this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM [DataItem] WHERE [LastName] = Potato
```

Which is clearly invalid. It could be worse though. What if a malicious user passed `1; drop table DataItem;#` ? That's how SQL injection attacks work.

You should *never* use string concatenation to pass values to a query. No amount of quoting is going to fix this problem either - what if someone is named `O'Reilly`? Quoting won't prevent a hacker from entering `Robert; drop table Students;--`. Look at [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

The correct and safe way is to use parameterised queries (aka server-bound parameters). Parameters aren't string replacements. They're sent alongside the query to the database, preserving their type, precision etc. They allow you to send eg a decimal number or date as a strongly-typed `decimal` or `DateTime` and never worry about string formats and separators.

I suspect you used [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). The package's Github page shows how to use parameterised queries in this case, by using `?` :

```
return Database.QueryAsync<DataItem>("SELECT * FROM [DataItem] WHERE [LastName] = ?", s);
```

`?` specifies a positional (ie unnamed) parameter. The parameter values you pass after the query text are used as the values for each `?` parameter, in the order they appear

Answer (score 0):

you need to delimit string parameters in SQL queries

```
return Database.QueryAsync<DataItem>
    ($"SELECT * FROM [DataItem] WHERE [LastName] = '{s}'");
```

as pointed out in the comments, parameterized queries are more secure

```
return Database.QueryAsync<DataItem>
    ("SELECT * FROM [DataItem] WHERE [LastName] = ?", s);
```

Comment: That's no different than the original bug. What happens if someone is named `O'Reilly`? Or `'; drop table DataItem; #` ?